# Show independence of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, independence

I'm having trouble showing the dependency of two random variables.

If I have n random variables $X_1,\cdots,X_n $ ~ $iid$ $(\,\mu,\sigma^2)$, how can I show that the $r$-th order statistics $X_{(r)}$ $(1<=r<=n)$ and the sample mean $\overline X$ are independent?

Comment: If you are told that the sample mean has value $3.257$, what do you know about $(X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}, \ldots, X_{(n)})$ that you did not already know? E.g. you already knew that for continuous random variables, $X_{(r)} < X_{(r+1)}$ a.s. and knowing that $\bar{X} = 3.257$ does not change that, or does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempt, but I think the statement is obviously untrue if I am reading it correctly.

Sample mean, by convolution we have:

$\bar X = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}$ ~  $f_X*...*f_X/n$

First order statistic, we only need the minimum, denote the RV as $Y$:

$f_Y(y)=-n(1-F_X(y))^{n-1}f_X(y)$

Recall that the following should hold for the RVs to be independent:

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) =f_X(x)f_Y(y) $

Now let's find a counter example. Set $n=1$ and substitute the RH side:

$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)\times-(1-F_X(y))\times f_X(y)$

Now set $y$ so that the $F_X(y)=1$ i.e. maximum of the support. For simplicity we can say that this value is one (as such distribution exists).

$f_{X,Y}(x,1)=f_X(x)$

But clearly, **if the minimum is one, the mean is also one** in this example with a single sample. Thus:

$f_{X,Y}(1,1)=f_X(x)$

Which could only hold if $X$ had a single valued distribution.